# When including your header, in PHP, how do you add things?

Tags: php, javascript

I am building one of my first PHP websites, and just playing around with it. I am going to be using PHP includes, so I only have to change my meta stuff once. Currently, I have everything from the doctype to the end of the `</head>`.

A friend is saying I should not include the `</head>` on the header.php, but instead, include it on each page, so I can add page specific stuff. Is that a good way of doing it?

Currently, for stuff like title, I was doing

```
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?>
```

and then on the top of each page, I was doing

```
<?php $page_title = 'Blah'; ?>
```

How would I add a page specific Javascript file if this is the way I'm doing this?

Comment: Yeah I think that's the way to go for best SEO you want to have different titles for different pages

Comment: Alright - quick other question to this, what if I want to include multiple pages on 1 index.php file. Is there a good way of doing it then?

Comment: See my updated answer. With this you could include different pages regarding the requested route coming from your .htaccess.

Answer (score 6):

What's going on here is you're trying to inject logic into your templates, which isn't necessarily wrong, but it produces more confusing and harder-to-maintain code. This issue isn't only with your `<title>` tags, but will keep coming up as your pages get more and more dynamic and complex (dynamic navigation, page-specific layouts, etc.).

An MVC approach solves this problem perfectly. MVC consists of models, which talk to your data sources (MySQL, Redis, whatever) and handle your logic; views, which render HTML; and controllers, which are sort of the glue between models and views. Each request a user makes is eventually routed to a controller and then an action method in your controller (for example: `/users/login` might map to the `User` controller and the `login` action).

You would set your page title (or any other meta information) in the action method in your controller, which knows what the request is but is invoked before the view is rendered:

```php
$request->setTitle('Home page');
```

And then in your view, simply render it:

```html
<title><?php echo $request->getTitle(); ?></title>
```

If you're just starting PHP, it's a great time to learn MVC because it'll get you into some good habits that affect not only your PHP development but any other development as well.

I recommend you check out [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) for its simplicity and excellent documentation. I used CodeIgniter for a while, but ended up [writing my own framework](http://github.com/jimmysawczuk/scaffolding) that fitted my needs better.

Comment: Long term a MVC approach is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: *"An MVC approach solves this problem perfectly."* but then you suggest setting the view's title in the *controller*... I really suggest that you think about that again ;-)

Comment: Where would you set it? If you set it in the view, it sort of defeats the point, and the model is agnostic to what action/template is requesting it.

Comment: "action method in your controller" I assume this is something in MVC? I'm fairly new to anything Server Side, but figured I would start somewhere. I have been doing HTML/CSS for over 3 years.

Comment: @David I added a little more summary to my answer, hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: This actually may be the best way for me to do it, one of the ideas I had was have a bunch of pages on 1 index.php page, and use .htaccess and rewrites to go to the certain part of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, how you build up your pages. But on a simple site, you could use an associative array like this:

```
$pages = array(
    'home' => array(
        'title' => 'Home',
        'metaDescription' => 'This is the home of my website',
        'metaKeywords' => 'A,B,C',
        'scripts' => '<script src="src/js/com.jquery/1.7/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>',
        'content' => 'home.phtml'
    ),
    'page_1' => …
);
```

And than you can recall it like this:

```
<head>
    […]
    <title><?php print $pages['home']['title']; ?></title>
    […]
    <?php print $pages['home']['scripts']; ?>
    […]
</head>
<body>
    <?php require '/pathToIncludes/' . $pages['home']['content]; ?> 
</body>
```

But I would only recommend this for a site with just a bunch of pages.

Comment: You said 2 thing, on a "Simple site", but you said you would only recommend it for a bunch of pages.

Comment: Argh. I'm not a native speaker. Thought "a bunch of" could also mean "just a few".

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do some logic first, then render it. Something like this:

```
<?php

$page = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'js' => array(
        'jquery.min.js',
    ),
    'copyright' => 'Copyright 2012',
);

if ( $needed ) {
    $page[ 'js' ][] = 'some-other.js';
}

include( 'header.php' );
include( 'content.php' );
include( 'footer.php' );


// header.php
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?= $page[ 'title' ]; ?></title>

        <? foreach ( $page[ 'js' ] as $js ) { ?>
            <script src="<?= $js"></script>
        <? } ?>

    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solve this problem:

- `start.php` connects to my database, includes my classes, sets all my default meta values
  into a `$page` object and starts `$_SESSION`
- `header.php` Spits out all my html top matter (doctype, `<head>` etc.) based on the values in `$page`
- `top.php` Includes `start.php` and `header.php`

For most files, the default values are fine. I just include `top.php`. For special cases where I need special values, my page looks like this:

```
<?php 
    include("start.php");
    $page->title = "My special title";
    include("header.php");
    // The rest of my content
?>
```

This has the added advantage that pages can have access to $_SESSION and other custom classes, and use that information to modify the header without getting the "header already sent" error. For example, you can validate some user input and redirect them using `location('header: foo.php');` or change the title depending on their login status.

For page specific javascript includes, I would create an array of urls to include `$page->javascript` and then put something like: `$page->javascript[] = "http://example.com/js/myScript.js";` between `start.php` and `header.php`

Comment: Eww, that seems like very bad practice.

Comment: Ok. Well - I like your idea more than the other ideas given, but I know ever page will have a different title. I would also like most pages to run off 1 index.php file, by using rewrites in .htaccess.